# S'asseoir en tailleur : la posture de l'artisan ou généralement les jambes croisées ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, professions

*S'asseoir en [tailleur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tailleur)* : *S'asseoir à plat, les jambes repliées et les genoux écartés* (*TLFi*), est attesté au 19<sup>e</sup> par référence au métier, alors que le tailleur s'asseyait d'une manière particulière (sur sa table de travail près des fenêtres, lit-on rapidement sur le *Web*) pour travailler ; de s’asseoir *en couturier* ou *comme les tailleurs*, 17<sup>e</sup> (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, éd. *Le Robert*). On y fait meilleure figure que l'apothicaire avec son [*quiproquo*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/quiproquo). Il s'agit d'une posture que *Wikipédia* classe par association à la [position du lotus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_du_lotus), mais avec les pieds sous les cuisses et non sur.

[image]
<sup>Image tirée de l'article [*tailleur*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tailleur) au *Wiktionnaire*</sup>

---

- Y a-t-il communément une différence entre *s'asseoir en tailleur* et
  *s'asseoir les jambes croisées sur le sol/par terre* ? Quand on parle de  *jambes [croisées](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crois%C3%A9es/2) en tailleur*, est-ce de la *veste* dont il est question ?

  - *S'asseoir en tailleur* peut-il signifier de manière [contemporaine](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27asseoir%20en%20tailleur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%27asseoir%20en%20tailleur%3B%2Cc0) autant la posture où l'on croise aux chevilles/tibias (pseudo-lotus), que celle où la racine du pied s'appuie exactement sur celle de l'autre, ou est-ce exclusivement celle où la racine des pieds est presque à plat sur le sol et les genoux très hauts (un peu comme sur l'image des tailleurs) ?
  - Demander à un groupe d'enfants à la petite école de *s'asseoir en tailleur* est-il usuel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'expression est fortement passée dans le registre commun et bien peu de gens feront spontanément le lien avec ses origines. Par contre, je ne pense pas qu'on puisse le lier au costume féminin, postérieur à l'expression.

S'asseoir en tailleur, c'est simplement s'asseoir par terre avec les jambes plus ou moins croisées. Les autres variantes sont "accroupi" ou "à genous". Les trois expressions peuvent être utilisées auprès d'un groupe d'enfants, quoique la position "à genou" de part son inconfort et une certaine connotation de soumission soit improbable.

Sur l'image, le tailleur de gauche sera considéré "en tailleur" et celui de droite est presque "accroupi".

Comment: Notons qu'une femme habillée en tailleur composé d'une veste et d'une jupe, qui s'assiérait en tailleur, montrerait certainement plus que ce qu'elle voudrait, il me paraît donc évident que l'expression fait effectivement référence au métier plutôt qu'au costume, qui soit dit en passant ne remonte qu'au début du XXème siècle, étant donc bien plus récent que l'expression.

Comment: Celui de droite est assis sur le sol (ou peut-être sur un coussin caché par la personne au premier plan) jambes écartées. Accroupi désigne une personne qui a les plantes de pieds sur le sol, les genoux complètement pliés et les fesses près des talons.

Comment: D'où mon "plutôt accroupi", vu que la position ne correspond pas tout à fait à la définition du dictionnaire.

Comment: Merci ! En fait je ne lie pas l'expression au costume féminin. C'est que les _jambes croisées en tailleur_ est composé sans le verbe s'asseoir et il n'y a donc aucune raison pour qu'obligatoirement ce soit rattaché au métier, et une veste croise : _nous nous mettions en rond, les jambes croisées en tailleur, pour nous partager..._ (Alain-Fournier, [Meaulnes](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ki4ssQmsdRgC&pg=PA32&dq=Meaulnes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUgsX50qLLAhVEuYMKHbmqDSA4ChDoAQg1MAI#v=onepage&q=tailleur&)) ; comme vous le dites le tailleur ne croise pas strictement les jambes dans sa posture...