# S'asseoir en Indien/à l'indienne : est-ce toujours uniquement un régionalisme du Québec ?

Tags: expressions, québec, régionalismes

*S'asseoir en [Indien](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=410805&rubrique=orig&boite=1)/[à l'indienne](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?no=410821&base=QU&boite=1)*. En résumé au Québec assis *à l'indienne/en Indien* signifiait d'abord techniquement assis *sur les talons* en référence à certaines traditions chez les peuples Amérindiens du Québec.<sup>1</sup> C'est au moins en partie de l'influence américaine (et de certains auteurs comme [*Chateaubriand*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois-Ren%C3%A9_de_Chateaubriand#Le_.C2.AB_voyage_.C2.BB_en_Am.C3.A9rique_du_Nord) qui relayent ces expériences avec les Amérindiens, ou de traductions de l'écrivain [James Fenimore Cooper](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fenimore_Cooper), par exemple) au lexique (*Indian*; Indien désignait surtout les peuples autochtones des colonies espagnoles et portugaises) comme en termes de référant (la posture, différente), que procèderait le passage de l'expression au sens [moderne](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=QU&no=410883&rubrique=&boite=1) des *jambes croisées devant soi* (d'ailleurs *s'asseoir [à la sauvage](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?no=408278&base=QU)* est vieilli et réfère à l'ancien sens.).<sup>2</sup>

---

- Vu l'influence d'auteurs comme Chateaubriand, les échanges etc., l'expression « *s'asseoir en Indien/à l'indienne* » est-elle aujourd'hui généralement comprise à l'extérieur du Québec ?
- Est-ce complètement figé ? A-t-on déjà entendu *s'asseoir à l'amérindienne/en Amérindien* et le cas échéant s'agissait-il du même sens ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> « Assis à l'indienne, jambes repliées sous lui, le sol de mousse pour fauteuil, Henderson les interrogea tous. En vain. » (Thériault, [*Agaguk*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mc7xAAAAMAAJ&dq=agaguk&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22assis%20%C3%A0%20l%27indienne%22), 1958)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> On paraphrase la *Base de données lexicographiques panfrancophone* (BDLP) ; voir les deux premiers liens. On s'inspire d'une [manchette](http://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/201603/01/01-4956128-inde-tous-en-bobettes-pour-eviter-la-tricherie-lors-dun-examen.php) pour la question ; voir aussi [*s'asseoir en tailleur*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17990).</sub>

Comment: En France, je n'ai jamais entendu « S'assoir à l'indienne », et même avec l'explication, je ne vois pas la position que cela représente...

Comment: Autant je ne dois pas réfléchir sur la position à prendre pour s'asseoir "en tailleur", autant celle correspondant à s'asseoir "à l'indienne" ne m'est pas intuitive du tout, même si avec l'explication je comprends le sens et l'origine. @Random : en gros, c'est être à genoux, avec les fesses posées sur les talons.

Comment: @LaurentS. Ah ok, merci ! Parce que "assis sur les talons", on peut avoir les genoux au sol ou en l'air... Donc c'est comme le salut au sol du Judo... Du coup, il doit y avoir une origine japonaise également...

Comment: C'est une des façons de s'agenouiller, sur les talons dans le cas présent - plutot que redressé en prière - l'équivalent du seiza japonnais, si je ne me trompe pas.

Comment: Not an answer, just an OT observation (& NOT to be confused w/an “Indian squat toilet”), but there’s the ["cross-legged, Indian squat"](https://books.google.com/books?id=pmEQAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22indian+squat%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22cross-legged%2C+Indian+squat%22) & a 1778 example that was already using a possible hybrid of the current sense (["jambes croisée" + "l'accroupissement"](https://books.google.com/books?id=SBmvTR7HIrAC&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=accroupissement&f=false#v=onepage&q=accroupissement&f=false)) to describe how "**N**aturels du pays" (albeit of the Pacific & not Quebec) sat.

Comment: Si on me dit de m'asseoir en Indien, aujourd'hui, c'est couramment un lotus relâché, ce n'est pas un truc technique. Je l'aurais dit sans hésiter à des enfants. @PapaPoule Interesting, sitting may not be required in the expression if it is to also mean "se blottir" like old [quatir](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/quatir), context may also differ from sitting to rest/talk. I do not have expertise, sadly, with the different traditions of the First Nations of North-America, such as the diff Can/U.S. - East/West. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En France, s’asseoir à l'indienne fait penser à se mettre en posture du lotus (*padmāsana*).
En général, le mot *indien* renvoie à *hindou* et non pas à *amérindien*, sauf évidemment dans les western.

En Inde, beaucoup de personnes s'assoient à l'indienne... ce que les dernières générations qui ont connues les chaises ne peuvent plus faire, l'articulation du genou ne s'étant plus adaptée au cours de la croissance : le plateau supérieur du tibia est horizontal, alors que la position sur les talons l'incline vers l'arrière.

Cette position est aussi connue en Afrique et en Amazonie par exemples, alors on dira s'asseoir "*à la manière des peuplades locales*"

Comment: "En général, le mot indien renvoie à hindou et non pas à amérindien, sauf évidemment dans les western." - moi, je trouve ça très intéressant. Merci.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord : on entend et voit souvent utiliser *indien* pour les amérindiens et *hindous* pour les habitants de l'Inde. Comme dans l'expression assez commune : "les cowboys et les indiens". Le terme *amérindien* n'étant pas si courant, y compris dans la prese généraliste, cela permet de faire la différence.

Comment: @MakorDal -- Depuis que l'Inde est intégrée dans les pays émergents BRICS (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%A9sil,_Russie,_Inde,_Chine_et_Afrique_du_Sud), *indien* [en France] fait de plus en plus référence à un habitant de l'Inde, et hindou à une des religions indiennes, ce qui oblige à préciser : les *indiens **d'Amérique*** pour qu'il n'y ait pas de confusion. La question se posait sur la *position assise*, et donc renvoie à l'Inde. Dans la légende l'amérindien est à cheval, tire à l'arc, a un tomawak et fume le calumet de la paix, et, très rarement en position accroupie sur les talons.

Comment: La notion de BRICS reste assez récente pour que la majorité de la population utilise encore la différence que j'ai cité.

Comment: Merci ! Ce serait donc une concurrence où l'expression passe, mais son contenu réfère plus à l'Inde (lotus) qu'aux coutumes ou origines amérindiennes, à l'extérieur du Québec. Possiblement que la même chose se produit avec l'_Indian style sitting_ en anglais. Parfois on réfère aussi à _à la Turque_, selon les influences. Le générique, "à la manière des peuplades locales" bien utile, si peu descriptif.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Si vous dites "siège à la turque", tout le monde va penser aux W.C. où il faut s'accroupir juste au-dessus du trou... parce que justement il n'y en a pas... de siège :)

Comment: Les indiens (le peuple de l'Inde) ne sont pas tous hindous.

Answer (score 0):

En France, "*s'asseoir à l'indienne*" se dit "*s'asseoir en tailleur*".

Comment: oui, à condition que cela ne désigne pas "assis sur ses talons" comme évoqué au début de la question.